# Problem creating PostGIS template database

Tags: macos, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to build a template geographic database for PostGIS (1.5) on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) for my GeoDjango application.

I am following: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis

I've managed to come up to the point where the provided postgis.sql should be run (i.e. `psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql`)

At that point I am getting an error at the first SQL statement that is tried to be run. When I try that on the psql prompt the result is as follows:

```
template_postgis=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION st_spheroid_in(cstring) RETURNS spheroid AS '/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-1.5','ellipsoid_in' LANGUAGE 'C' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
NOTICE:  type "spheroid" is not yet defined
DETAIL:  Creating a shell type definition.
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-1.5.so": dlopen(/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-1.5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _DatumGetFloat4
  Referenced from: /usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-1.5.so
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/postgres 
 in /usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis1.5.so
```

Any ideas what might have been messed up?

Comment: Weird error.  How did you install PostGIS?  Have had the best luck with the KyngChaos frameworks on OS X.

Comment: first i tried mac ports but it didn't went well, as it tried to reinstall already existing dependencies, etc. so i went the KyngChaos way.

Comment: i have psql and pg_config and other binaries both under `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/` and `/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/`. does this give a clue about the mess?

Comment: i removed `/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/` manually and installed postgresql 9.0.1 and postgis 1.5.2 using KyngChaos binaries but no luck. i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the correct pre-requisite libraries installed. I got this same error when I had GEOS v2 installed, and an upgrade to v3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set up my template database for PostGIS
[Landsliding Into PostGIS With KML Files](http://www.philwhln.com/landsliding-into-postgis-with-kml-files)

Comment: thanks. still no luck. at the point where the sql statements should be run (under `/usr/local/pgsql-9.0/share/contrib/postgis-1.5` in my setup) i get an `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory` error as the `$libdir` in the sql script cannot be resolved. i replaced that variable with the actual path in the sql file (i.e. `/usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/postgis-1.5`). then i am getting the error mentioned in the question. i have no idea why and from where this `/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/postgres` is being referenced.

Comment: Is it possible to uninstall both versions and start again? I recommend using Homebrew

Comment: i couldn't uninstall. if i could, this would solve the problems. but although i re-installed the postgis, it still goes for the postgresql83 directory which doesn't even exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the Shared Object is not found. The most obvious reason is that PostGIS has not been installed (properly). Furthermore, the order in which the SQL Scripts from the contrib/postgis-1.5 folder are installed is important.

I have used this order and (Linux shell commands) successfully:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d database -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib/_int.sql
$ psql -U postgres -d database  -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib/pg_trgm.sql
$ psql -U postgres -d database  -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
$ psql -U postgres -d database  -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

After this, there should be somewhere around 800 functions, a few new types and some overloaded operator available.

Comment: thanks. apparently there is a mess about the installation. i don't know what and i cannot roll all back and begin from start. if i could uninstall all that, that would also do. i had done this before on my previous dev environment mac ox x 10.5.

Comment: @omat You can drop the gis function from the database. If they are available, the problem should be somewhere else but since your error message points out that "spheroid" is not defined, you are missing some imports.